# Headless chrome and html parser string

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, headless-browser

I'm currently using selenium and BeautifulSoup to scrape a website but I'm running into two major issues, first of all, I can't get Chrome to launch in headless mode and it says there are multiple unexpected ends of inputs ([photo of said errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzT2v.png)). The other problem I have is that I keep getting an error on the line that contains "html.parser" saying that a 'str' is not a callable object. Any advice on these issues would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import urllib.request
import lxml
import html5lib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#config options
options = Options()
options.headless = True

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://tokcount.com/?user=mrsam993'

# Connect to the URL
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='D:\chromedriver') #chrome_options=options
browser.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source(), "html.parser")
browser.quit()

# for i in range(10):
links = soup.findAll('span', class_= 'odometer-value')
print(links)
```

Comment: try without brackets ```browser.page_source```

Answer (score 0):

As for the headless you need to call this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
...
```

the page_source is not a method. So you need to remove the brackets:

```
browser.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to launch to launch chrome in headless mode,and parse the content to html with BeautifulSoup4, this is what you can do:

```
#Importing necessary packages
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

url = 'https://tokcount.com/?user=mrsam993' 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
options.headless = True 

with webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) as driver: #modified 
    driver.get(url)
    
    print("Page URL: ", driver.current_url)
    print("Page title: ", driver.title)

    #Get the source page
    html = driver.page_source

ParsedContent = soup(html, 'html.parser')
ParsedContent
```

Make sure you have the following packages: Selenium, webdriver manager.

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver_manager
```